# Rename files by batch based on the name

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to rename a file by batch based on the number that is in his name and if it has not put zero at the beginning?

Note: The name can be varied, just what does not change is the file extension.

```
Example:

_videoteste_01.mp4 = 01.mp4
videoteste02.mp4 = 02.mp4
03videoteste.mp4 = 03.mp4
vidteste4.mp4 = 04.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [JREN.BAT hybrid JScript/batch utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) can do what you ask quite easily. JREN.BAT renames files by doing a regular expression search and replace on the name. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP forward.

But I must say that your proposed naming scheme could quite easily run into problems. What if you attempt to rename "abc5.mp4" and "05xyz.mp4"? - Both files will get the same name, and the second rename will fail. The same problem exists if you have two files without any number in the name - both would get 00.mp4.

Here is the JREN call that would implement your proposed scheme:

```
jren "^\D*(\d*).*\.mp4$" "($1?lpad($1,'00'):'00')+'.mp4'" /j /i /p "c:\video test"
```

**Update based on comment:**

You can use the following to rename all files, regardless of extension. It will preserve the extension of each file.

```
jren "^\D*(\d*).*(\.[^.]*)$" "($1?lpad($1,'00'):'00')+$2" /j /i /p "c:\video test"
```

Comment: Where I intend to use, it is difficult occur this because the files never teram the same number ... Thanks for the code, it worked perfectly now I can organize my videos without any complication.


Note: Could you tell me how I would do to be able to use in any format without having q change the script example

.txt
.avi

and etcs ...

Comment: I would ask you one last help, how do I set a directory for the script act (with or without spaces).

Example:

C:\Test

C:\VIDEO TEST -- 
Thanks for everything here.

Comment: @HumbertoFreitas - I edited both codes to include the /P option to set the path where the files are. Use JREN /? from the command line to get help on all the options.